# link checker for hotfile, rapidshare

Tags: performance, hyperlink

i have over 20k links to check.
those are rapidshare and fileserve links.
right now i'm using 'file_get_content' and check if a fileserve link content contain 'This file was either in breach of a copyright holder or deleted by the uploader.' to mark it as 'deleted' and 'File not found.' for rapidshare link.

```
if (strpos($var2, "This file was either in breach of a copyright holder or deleted by the uploader.")) {...
if (strpos($var, "File not found.")) {...
```

thing is that file_get_content is really really slow even when i added this:

```
$context = stream_context_create(array('http' => array('header'=>'Connection: close')));
$var = file_get_contents($url,false,$context);
```

if there any other alternative way to do it faster?
script is running for over an hour and i have 5k links checked...

Answer (score 0):

Do you try multi-thread and other language like C to do that check?

Answer (score 0):

Both these service provide API to the public, read their docs.